# GWT How to use same service in different modules

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to run a gwt project. This project has 3 modules. 
1-StudentSystem2
2-EnterStudent 
3-GetStudent.

I want to enter student id,name,department in enter class and when i click add button add them to database and change window. But when click add button it gives

No file found for: /com.example.studentsystem2.client.enterStudent.enterStudent/dao

and prints xxx. how can i connect two modules in dao service??

Here is the package structure.(sorry not to load image because of the lack of reputation)

```
com.example.studentSystem2
   ->  studentSystem2.gwt.xml
 |com.example.studentsystem2.client
   ->  StudentSystem2.java 
    ||com.example.studentSystem2.client.enterStudent
      ->enterStudent.gwt.xml
    ||com.example.studentSystem2.client.enterStudent
      ->Enter.java
      ->EnterStudent.java
      ->Enter.ui.xml

    ||com.example.studentSystem2.client.getStudent
      ->getStudent.gwt.xml
    ||com.example.studentSystem2.client.getStudent
      ->Get.java
      ->GetStudent.java
      ->Get.ui.xml
    ||com.example.studentSystem2.client.request
      ->Dao.java
      ->DaoAsync.java
      ->EMF.java
      ->StudentInfo.java
 |com.example.studentSystem2.server
   ->DaoImpl.java
```

here is the onClick method in Enter.java

```
    @UiHandler("addButton")
        void onAddButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            dao.addStudentInfo(IdTextField.getText(),nameTextField.getText(),departmentTextField.getText(),new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                    System.out.println("xxx");
                }

                public void onSuccess(Void ignore) {
                    Window.Location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8888/GetStudent.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
                }
            });
  }
```

and the Dao.java class

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("dao")
public interface Dao extends RemoteService {
    public List<StudentInfo> listInfos();
    public void addStudentInfo(String SId, String name, String department);
    public void remove(String id);


}
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to skin this cat. Have you considered dependency injection at all?

Comment: i had no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **'N'** ways. One way which I favor is, keep your service and its implementation in a separate module. Then add this module as a dependency to your other modules. Then you are able to access the same service for which you had added the dependency.

Comment: you mean this architecture is not proper??